# Simulate the interaction with a CLI

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, functional-testing, end-to-end

I have a CLI that can launch processes, especially interactive shells and waits for them, they can be closed using the same CLI. I need to create some end to end tests for it using bash but I cannot see how to simulate the execution in the terminal; the output should be sent to the process in the "foreground".

Suppose that executing `my-cli start` launches a python script that start a subprocess (running an interactive shell) and waits to it.
in the testing script, `exec(my-cli start)` will replace the current process with the process running python script and not the interactive shell, so I cannot interact with the interactive shell after.

I thought about using pipes, but I think something that can simulate using a terminal will be better, any ideas ?

Example:

Suppose the code of my CLI (`cli.py`) is:

```
import subprocess


process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i'], shell=False)
process.communicate()
```

Using `expect` I don't know if it's possible to communicate with the interactive shell (`/bin/bash -i`)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


spawn python3 cli.py

#expect eof

send -- "echo $$\r"
```

Comment: [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) is a tool that you can use for testing of interactive commands.

Comment: As for `exec` running `spawn my-cli start` will not interact with the spawned interactive shell, it will communicate with the process running python code I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by Benjamin. I and many others have used `expect` in this scenario. As long as you can tell the text that will be presented in the terminal then you can use the following web pages as a guide to creating an expect script.

- https://www.poftut.com/expect-scripting-tutorial-examples/
- https://www.shellscript.sh/expect.html
- https://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial

Update based on the example provided. For this, I have a file foo.py:

```py
import subprocess


process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i'], shell=False)
process.communicate()
```

An expect file (expect-example.exp):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn  python3 foo.py

expect "*bash*"
send "date\r"
send "exit\r"

interact
```

When I run this `expect expect-example.exp` I get the following:

```
$ expect expect-example.exp 
spawn python3 foo.py
bash-3.2$ date
Mon  3 Jun 2019 14:03:37 BST
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
$
```

It is worth mentioning, given that I am running a single command `date` and I want to see the output from it I must include the `interact` command at the end of the script. Otherwise, my expect script will exit as soon as it has sent the date command and won't wait for the response.

Comment: I added an example, please take a look.

Comment: when `spawn  python3 foo.py` Expect should interact with the process running python not with its subprocess, am I wrong ? do they share the same file identifiers ?